# angularfire: Issue with ..priority coming in data object in the ng-repeat

Tags: firebase, angularfire

//controller code.

```
var fireurl = 'https://someuerid.firebaseio.com/'
var usersref = new Firebase(fireurl);
angularFire(usersref.limit(10), $scope, "userConcalls");
```

//view code

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in userConcalls">key:{{key}} value: {{value}} </li>
```

Error
Uncaught Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: ".priority". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. But it looks like you were violating the character set limitations for Firebase references. How exactly does you data structure look like? See https://www.firebase.com/docs/creating-references.html